# Dynamically preselected dropdowns with angular

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-directive

In javascript, I have two arrays of objects and am trying to create dropdowns in the html using angular.js:

```
$scope.members=[
    {name: "Paul", position: "Vocals"},
    {name: "John", position: "Guitar"},
    {name: "George", position: "Guitar"},
    {name: "Ringo", position: "Drums"}
];

$scope.positions=[
    {label: "Guitar"},
    {label: "Vocals"},
    {label: "Drums"}
];
```

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="position in positions">
        {{member.position}}
    </option>
</select>
```

The current HTML is taking the member's position and duplicating it 3 times as the only option in the dropdown. For example, upon loading the page, Ringo's position is preselected as "drums" in the dropdown (that's the way it should be). But when clicking on the dropdown,the options for Ringo are "drums" and "drums", and "drums". They should be "drums", "vocals", and "guitar".

Is there a way to have all the options available AND have the correct one preselected on loading? What's the proper directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS has a directive specifically for select controls. Use it instead of `ng-repeat`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

[working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DLx8U0QvnipMH6lgyGt1?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.members = [
        {name: "Paul", position: "Vocals", alive: true},
        {name: "John", position: "Guitar", alive:  false},
        {name: "George", position: "Guitar", alive:  false},
        {name: "Ringo", position: "Drums", alive: true}
    ];
    
    $scope.positions = [
        {label: "Guitar"},
        {label: "Vocals"},
        {label: "Drums"}
    ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="member in members">
                {{member.name}}
                <select ng-options="position.label as position.label for position in positions" ng-model="member.position"></select>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="member.alive">Alive?</input>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <pre>
{{members | json}}
        </pre>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This solution provides the dropdown with the correct options but doesn't preselect anything. On loading, the dropdown is blank.

Comment: If you want something pre-selected, set $scope.selectedBeetle = $scope.members[0]; (or whichever one you want pre-selected) in the same place you assign your arrays to the $scope.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a fixed value? In that particular case (where $scope.selectedBeetle = $scope.members[0] AKA Paul), the default selection in the dropdown would be "vocals" for all members instead of just one.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing with a binary variable like a checkbox? For example, there would be another category in members called "alive". If alive==true/false the checkbox would be checked/unchecked by default.

I know this can be done with jade but I'm wondering if it can be done with plain HTML or angular...

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model="selectedBeetle" ng-options="member as member.name for member in members"></select>
<select ng-model="selectedBeetle.position" ng-options="position.label for position in positions"></select>
```

Comment: This solution provides the dropdown with the correct options but doesn't preselect anything. On loading, the dropdown is blank.

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low quality and is up for review. Might I request you to kindly improve your answer by specifying what the code that you have provided does, explaining the expressions used in the directives